Referencing templates using a variable from a different repo in the same Azure DevOps project
I've built a pipeline that makes use of a couple of repositories within my project.
All of these are declared in the resources block and are referenced by tag using:
ref: refs/tags/$(variableName)
and that's exactly what I want to achieve.
The problem I'm facing is related to a single repository from which I want to load a bunch of templates into my main pipeline. Due to that, whenever I'm calling a template, I use the name of the repo in it:
- template: templateName.yml@myRepoForTemplates
When things look as described above, I get the following error:
/azure-pipelines.yml: Could not get the latest source version for repository myRepoForTemplates hosted on Azure Repos using ref refs/tags/$(variableName).
When I changed the way I referenced the variable to a 'template parameter', so as follows:
ref: refs/tags/${{ variables.variableName }}, the error changed as well:
/azure-pipelines.yml: Could not get the latest source version for repository myRepoForTemplates hosted on Azure Repos using ref refs/tags/.
The change of the error message forces me to think that the variable is taken as a literal when a repo is used for template calls. The fun thing is that if I don't use a variable in the repo declaration and provide a tag directly there, everything works properly.
Is it a DevOps bug? Is there any way to overcome it?
I'd be more than grateful for your help.
Cheers
EDIT: @Bright Ran-MSFT below you can find the yaml code:
yml-config/variables.yml
variables:
  serviceConnectionName: '#myConn#'
  subscription-id: '#mySubId'
  destroyPlan: 'false'
  cicd-templates-version: '0.0.1'
  tf-modules-version: '0.0.1'
  tf-templates-version: '0.0.1'
  tf-bin-version: '1.5.7'

azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
  - none

variables:
- template: yml-config/variables.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: tf-templates
    type: git
    name: myProject/tf-templates
    ref: refs/tags/$(tf-templates-version)

  - repository: tf-modules
    type: git
    name: myProject/tf-modules
    ref: refs/tags/$(tf-modules-version)

  - repository: cicd-templates
    type: git
    name: myProject/cicd-templates
    ref: refs/tags/$(cicd-templates-version)

stages:
- template: yaml/tf-backend-setup.yml@cicd-templates
  parameters:
    serviceConnectionName: $(serviceConnectionName)
    subId: $(subscription-id)

- ${{ if eq(variables.destroyPlan, 'false') }}:
  - template: yaml/tf-execution.yml@cicd-templates
    parameters:
      serviceConnectionName: $(serviceConnectionName)
      subId: $(subscription-id)
      tfBinVersion: $(tf-bin-version)
      env: 'base'
      destroyPlan: $(destroyPlan)

- template: yaml/tf-execution.yml@cicd-templates
  parameters:
    serviceConnectionName: $(serviceConnectionName)
    subId: $(subscription-id)
    tfBinVersion: $(tf-bin-version)
    env: 'prod'
    destroyPlan: $(destroyPlan)

- template: yaml/tf-execution.yml@cicd-templates
  parameters:
    serviceConnectionName: $(serviceConnectionName)
    subId: $(subscription-id)
    tfBinVersion: $(tf-bin-version)
    env: 'dev'
    destroyPlan: $(destroyPlan)

- ${{ if eq(variables.destroyPlan, 'true') }}:
  - template: yaml/tf-execution.yml@cicd-templates
    parameters:
      serviceConnectionName: $(serviceConnectionName)
      subId: $(subscription-id)
      tfBinVersion: $(tf-bin-version)
      env: 'base'
      destroyPlan: $(destroyPlan)

The two repos that contain TF code work properly and are checked out based on the respective variables' value.
As long as I'm not calling templates using the path@repo syntax (i.e. - template: yaml/tf-execution.yml@cicd-templates) the third repo works ok as well.
If I introduce the path@repo call, I get the aforementioned errors, almost as if the ref value was treated differently.
Thanks in advance for your help!

The repositories resource is expanded at compile time, only the static variables and parameters can be evaluated at compile time.
So, for your case:

If you want to set the value of ref key via a pipeline variable, you need set a static variable like as below. By this way, the pipeline will always reference the tag specified by the static variable until you update its value to a new tag in the YAML file.
# Define the static variable and explicitly set its value.
variables:
  tagName: v1.2

resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: myRepoForTemplates
      type: git
      name: string
      ref: refs/tags/$(tagName)


If you want to dynamically set the value of tagName when triggering the pipeline run, you can define it as a parameter like as below. By this way, when you manually trigger the pipeline, you can specify the value of the parameter. Otherwise, the pipeline will use the default value.
# Define the parameter with default value.
parameters:
- name: tagName
  type: string
  default: v1.2

resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: myRepoForTemplates
      type: git
      name: string
      ref: refs/tags/${{ parameters.tagName }}





EDIT:
The problem might be with the order of evaluation for the resources, templates and user-defined variables. The user-defined variables (both in variables.yml and in azure-pipelines.yml) could be expanded after resources and templates.
When expanding the templates, the system will try to expand the contents in the template YAML files from the specified ref version of the repository resource. Since the variable values has not been expanded, the expression "$(tagName)" or "${{ variables.tagName }}" cannot get the actual value.
For your case, you can try to use the parameters instead of variables to set the ref. The parameters can be priority expanded at compile time. So, the following should work for you:
parameters:
- name: cicd-templates-version
  type: string
  default: '0.0.1'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: cicd-templates
    type: git
    name: myProject/cicd-templates
    ref: refs/tags/${{ parameters.cicd-templates-version }}

stages:
- template: path/to/template.yml@cicd-templates



I'm following all the points you mentioned.
I have static variables only.
I have three repos, all declared the same way.
Everything works if I don't call templates - if I do it (and I do it only for one of those repos), then the errors start to show up.

@BartP, Please post the YAML of your pipeline. And explain when it works and when it does not?

I added the code and context in the first message. Cheers!

It seems to be working when I switch from static variables to template parameters, but the issue still persists when static variables are used.

It makes sense now with the variables being resolved later on during the cycle, but I'm still clueless why the rest of the repos get checked out properly. After all I provided these values for them the same way.

@BartP, "but I'm still clueless why the rest of the repos get checked out properly. " Which stages or jobs to check out the repos?

tf-backend-setup.yml and tf-execution.yml (which both are stages underneath and contains at least two jobs) check out (at least in one of the jobs) : self, cicd-templates, tf-modules, tf-templates.
The conundrum which I cannot comprehend is why ref gets resolved properly, when there are no path@repo calls and the moment I introduce them, ref becomes interpreted as a literal - $(variableName) seems to be no longer treated as a variable reference.
`

@BartP, I have updated my above answer with more information (see EDIT). Check and try with it.

Thanks @Bright Ran-MSFT. Switching to template parameters solved the issue entirely. Thank you very much!
The behaviour we spotted here regarding ref/tags/$(variableName) being resolved properly when there is no path@repo call and ref/tags/$(variableName) being taken literally when the aforementioned call is present remains interesting.
